# jQuery doesn't recognize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an .js file that has certain functions:

```
$(function(){
    function slideDown(class) {

        var className = class;

        $('.slide_' + className).slideDown('slow', function() {

        });
    }
});
```

(And yes i added the .js file in the heading and it's showing in the firebug console.)

And i got an link that calls the function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="slideDown('.$x.');" class="info">i</a>
```

But when i press the button my firebug gives the following error:

> ReferenceError: slideDown is not defined

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `onclick` on the markup when you're using jQuery? Seems contradictory...

Comment: `slideDown` is defined only within your jQuery `ready()` callback.

Comment: Im using onclick cause i have multiple links in that container and definining the certain link would mean alot of text, but i guess both options would be alright?

Comment: I recommend to use the jQuery selectors. In your ``ready()`` jQuery function just use ``$(".info").click(slideDown)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `slideDown` in another function so it is only available inside that function, declare it outside the function so it will have global scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error with the variable `class`. Please use another variable name

> Error: `class` is a reserved identifier

Comment: This was one of the problems, but the declaring outside an other function was the biggest problem so im gone mark that as an answer. But i would like to thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

$x is undefined, i guess this code is for php

```
<a href="#" onclick="slideDown('<?=$x?>');" class="info">i</a>
```

Comment: $x isn't undefined it's part of the total code, but thanks for your input.